# javascript nested array update

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array that is populated like this:

```
var orderDetails = [];
    orderDetails.push({
    City: "ABQ",
    Banana: 5,
    Mango:12
    });
```

I am looping through a list of cities. I would like to be able to look in this array to see if the city exists and if it does, update the count of Banana and Mango. If it does not exist, I want to push the new City and Banana and Mango counts for that city into the array.

Can someone show me how this can be done? Note: I am using Server side javascript.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried ? This part I don't really understand `update the count of Banana and Mango. If it does not exist, it pushes the new City and Banana and Mango counts for that city into the array.` Update the count with what, what new City etc?

Comment: I vote to close because it's unclear.

Comment: I am pulling the data from the backend table. If the city already exists in the array, I want to update the count for each of the attributes. If it does not exist in the array, I want to push the new city and its attributes into the array. Hope that is clearer. As I mentioned, I am looping through a list of cities, each with a count of mango and bananas.

Comment: If you mean you want to sum up the duplicates values and make the duplicates unique I think you have the correct answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `array.prototype.find` if the object is already in your array:

```js
function update(arr, obj) {
    var found = arr.find(o => o.City === obj.City);
    if (found) {
        found.Banana += obj.Banana;
        found.Mango += obj.Mango;
    } else {
        arr.push(obj);
    }
}

var orderDetails = [];
update(orderDetails, {City: "ABQ", Banana: 5, Mango:12});
update(orderDetails, {City: "XXX", Banana: 1, Mango:3});
update(orderDetails, {City: "ABQ", Banana: 5, Mango:12});

console.log(orderDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a city while you're looping through the list of the cities. if you find it, you can update the two value, and you can push a new object otherwise.

```
cities.forEach(city => {
    var found = orderDetails.find(detail => detail.City === city.name);
    if (found) {
        found.Banana += city.banana;
        found.Mango += city.mango;
    } else {
        orderDetails.push({
            City: city.name,
            Banana: city.banana,
            Mango: city.mango,
        });
    }
});
```